# DropDown menu is not showing values of the passed array

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

The values of skillList is not showing in the drop down.it shows an empty dropdown.(the data fetched from api is pushed into the skillList array without any issue)

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 let skillList = [];
 export class DataCheck extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
         super(props)

         this.state = {
             skill: "",
             skillId: "",
         }
        this. handleSkillChange=this. handleSkillChange.bind(this);

     }
     componentDidMount() {
    // worker skill selection

         fetch("http://localhost:3001/dataservices/getallskills")
         .then (res=>res.json())
         .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
            let temArray = {};
            for (let i = 0; i < res.recordsets[0].length; i++) {
               temArray["value"] = res.recordsets[0][i].SkillId;
               temArray["label"] = res.recordsets[0][i].SkillTitle;
               skillList.push(temArray);
               console.log(skillList);
               temArray = {};
              }
             })
            .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            });
          }

       handleSkillChange(skill) {
        this.setState({
         skill: skill,
         skillId: skill.value
         });
       }

    render() {
         return (
            <div>

                 <form>
                <select
                      value={this.state.skill}
                      onChange={this.handleSkillChange}
                      options={skillList}
                      placeholder="Skills"
                       />

                   </form>
                   </div>
             )
         }
       }

  export default DataCheck


when I check the dev-tools, it shows like this:

  options:Array

         0:Object
           label:"wood works"
           value:6
```

(Array consists of 16 objects like this)

console says:

warning.js:36 Warning: Unknown prop `options` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native `select` does not have an `options` props. You have to manually `map` the `option` tag:

```
<select
  value={this.state.skill}
  onChange={this.handleSkillChange}
  placeholder="Skills"
>
  {this.state.skillList.map((optionSkill) => (
    <option value={optionSkill.value}>{optionSkill.label}</option>
  )}
</select>
```

Currently you have added `skillList` as a normal variable with module scope. Even though you have changed `skillList`, the same will not be reflected in the UI because React does not detect this change. you will have to change `skillList` to a state variable for React.

```
this.state = {
  skill: "",
  skillId: "",
  skillList: []
}

fetch("http://localhost:3001/dataservices/getallskills")
  .then (res=>res.json())
  .then(res => {
     this.setState({
       skillList: res.recordsets[0].map((recordSet) => ({
         label: recordSet.SkillTitle,
         value: recordSet.SkillId,
       }))
     });       
  });
```

Comment: now it doesn't show an error.but still the dropdown is empty

Comment: I was off the impression that `skillList` was something in state, will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `option` tag inside `select`. Loop array of items using `.map` and you will get your result. 
This codepen can help you to make this work,
[select example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/JbbEzX?editors=0010)

Hope this can help you!